# Missing polygons while using Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, reproducible-research

I'm trying to reproduce a code to display polygons in a map in another computer, however, in one computer the polygons are not shown. Does someone had this kind of problem while sharing code?
You can download the shapefile from here: http://www.conabio.gob.mx/informacion/metadata/gis/muni_2012gw.xml?_xsl=/db/metadata/xsl/fgdc_html.xsl&_indent=no

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(leaflet)

Mex <- readOGR(dsn="C:/DISCO D", layer="Muni_2012gw")
Mex_sub <- Mex[Mex$CVE_ENT=="01",]



bins <- quantile(Mex_sub@data$OID_1, c(0,.125,.25, .5, .75,.875, 1))
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = Mex_sub@data$OID_1, bins = (bins),
                na.color = "grey40", reverse = FALSE)

centr <- gCentroid(Mex_sub)@coords
leaflet(Mex_sub, options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 4, maxZoom = 15)) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(centr[1], centr[2], zoom = 8) %>%
  addPolygons(data=Mex_sub, weight = 1,fill = ~OID_1, fillColor = ~pal(OID_1),
              opacity=1, fillOpacity = 0.5, color=grey(0.5))
```

[image: Map in my computer]

[image: Map in the other computer]

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example to see if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've edited the previous post to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I see all the polygons. We would need more information to explain why it does not work on the other computer. Does it have the same R and packages versions?

Comment: Seems that the most recent version of leaflet and rgdal were the problem. It's working now on both computers.